# Trimming Digits in Wolfram From Right to Left

Tags: numbers, wolfram-mathematica, calculation

Before asking my question, let me clarify that, i have no to moderate knowledge of wolfram mathematica. I have a registration number and i want to extract the last two digits in wolfram mathematica for creating a calculation sheet. The number is given as following;
RegistrationNumber = 1555734;
LastTwoDigits= ? That's all.

Comment: `LastTwoDigits = RegistrationNumber  % 100`

Comment: Please explain a little bit. I copied and pasted the same code and got output as 1555734 %100.

Comment: Yes. That is what i am asking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

### Use modulo

When an integer is divided by 100 the remainder corresponds to its last two digits, so you can just use modulo 100 like stated in the comments.
Please note that in Wolfram Language the % symbol is not used for modulo, but it's [shorthand notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html#:%7E:text=Shorthand%20notations%20are%20a%20part,workflow%20in%20the%20Wolfram%20Language.) for the [Out](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) built-in function.

The correct function is [Mod](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html):

```
Mod[1555734, 100] (* output: 34 *)
```

### Use built-in functions

If you need more flexibility, I suggest using [IntegerDigits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html?q=IntegerDigits) and [FromDigits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html):

```
base = 10;
length = 2;

digitsList = IntegerDigits[1555734, base, length]; (* output: {3, 4} *)

FromDigits[digitsList] (* output: 34 *)
```

### Keep the zeros

Please note that both Mod and FromDigits return an integer which of course can't begin with a zero:

```
Mod[1555704, 100] (* output: 4 *)
FromDigits[{0, 4}] (* output: 4 *)
```

If you need the digits as characters, just convert each one to a string and then join them:

```
digitsList = IntegerDigits[1555704, base, length] (* output: {0, 4} *)

StringJoin[ToString /@ digitsList] (* output: "04" *)
```